# When trying to update node on ubuntu it fails with linux-image-extra... not going to be installed

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I have ran the following to try and update node but get the following output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo: unable to resolve host phil: Resource temporarily unavailable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-33-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am really confused with this as I do not understand what I should do. Any advice to resolve this and update my node to version 8?

Answer (score 0):

I solved exactly the same problem with unmet dependencies.

Run:

```
    sudo apt-get -f install
```

Firstly, you must solve all the problems related to unmet dependencies in order to install something using `apt-get install`

Then, I suggest to install NodeJS using NVM, this link could help you:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-node-js-en-ubuntu-16-04-es